# elegant implementation of increment button with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, increment

In my toy project to learn javascript and jQuery, I need to implement increment and decrement buttons for some input fields. I am thinking that the below design should work, but somehow it doesn't. Am I misunderstanding something about jQuery, or is it a banal error?

```
<button type="button"  id="WS1inc" class="incbut"> + </button>  
<input type="number" id="WS1" value="1">        


function increment(field)
{
    field.val(field.val()+1);
}

$("#WS1inc").click($("#WS1"),increment);
```

The console says that the object does not have method "val()", so I guess I can't pass jQuery objects like this?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MycnR/

EDIT: In response to my discussion with Blender, some more extensive HTML:
http://jsfiddle.net/4ELhf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you don't pass the field.

You may change the call to

```
$("#WS1inc").click(function(){increment($("#WS1")});
```

When you use `eventData` (the first argument you pass to `click`), those data aren't passed as argument directly to the handler but in `event.data`. So you can also do this :

```
function increment(e) {
    e.data.val(parseInt(e.data.val(), 10) +1);
}
$("#WS1inc").click($("#WS1"),increment);
```

Note that you must also parse the string in order to increment.

About this `eventData` argument, I found that [the documentation of `on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is clearer :

> Data to be passed to the handler in event.data when an event is
>   triggered.

Comment: so, how is "eventData" supposed to be used? Going by http://api.jquery.com/click/, I was assuming that my syntax above was equivalent to what you've shown me?

Comment: @dystroy I think my implementation is more elegant ;-)

Comment: @Alnitak Maybe, as I was mostly explaining the problem. But I don't like your `||this` : this should only be done if used because it might hide bugs more often than it solves problems.

Comment: @Alnitak but I agree with you there is no law against using native functions directly instead of adding a layer to fetch an element or its value. Personally I almost never use `val()`...

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues here.

`field.val()+1` is going to be classed as string concatenation rather than integer incrementation. You need to `parseInt()` first in order for this to calculate correctly.

Secondly, there is an issue with how you are calling `increment()`.

Change your code to:

```
function increment(field)
{
    field.val(parseInt(field.val(),10)+1);
}

$("#WS1inc").click(function(){
   increment($("#WS1"));
});
```

***Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/MycnR/2/*

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#WS1inc").click(function(){
     $("#WS1").val(parseInt($("#WS1").val())+1);
});
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/MycnR/1/

Answer (score 1):

You've got the syntax mixed up a little. Here's a super verbose way of doing it:

```
$("#WS1inc").click(function() {
    var $element = $("#WS1");
    var value = $element.val();
    var value_as_integer = parseInt(value, 10);

    $element.val(value_as_integer + 1);
});
```

Comment: yes, but in this case I would have to write that for each increment button (I will have several). While I can certainly do that, isn't there a way to just make a single increment function?

Comment: @Kaare: Not really. You're just not using the `id` attribute properly here. Give those elements meaningful class names and you can change this code slightly to account for all of the elements at once.

Comment: I don't understand. If I have 5 increment buttons and 5 input fields, which each have to be connected pairwise, surely I need distinct handles for each button and field, since pressing button 1 should only increment field 1, and not fields 2-5?

Comment: @Kaare: There's always a way to make a generic event handler. Post your HTML.

Comment: I have included a link in the original question

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the `increment` function which element it has to change.

This can be done using the `data` parameter to the `.on()` call, where the supplied parameter is available as `ev.data` within the event handler:

```
function increment(ev) {
     var el = ev.data || this;  // use the clicked element if it wasn't supplied
     el.value = parseInt(el.value, 10) + 1;
}

$('#WS1inc').on('click', document.getElementById('WS1'), increment);
```

Note the use of `el.value` - there's no need to use `$(el).val()` in most circumstances and `el.value` is far more efficient.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/W8fjX/

Comment: He is incrementing another field

Comment: @mplungjan oops - so he is!

Comment: well, you could use `$('#el').get(0)`.  There's no law against using native DOM inside jQuery code, anyway!  Often it's incredibly more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument passed to an event handler is the event object. 
In jquery, the context of the event handler (`this`) is set to the element that listened to that event... maybe you could relate to that and might want to change your function to :

```
function increment(){
    var field = $(this).siblings('input');
    field.val( (+field.val() || 0) + 1);
}
```

Here's a live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/MycnR/5/

Comment: He is incrementing another field

Answer (score 1):

Generic function:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/eq48m/)

html

```
<button type="button"  id="WS1dec" class="but"> - </button>  
<input type="number" id="WS1" value="1">        
<button type="button"  id="WS1inc" class="but"> + </button>  
<hr/>
<button type="button"  id="WS2dec" class="but"> - </button>  
<input type="number" id="WS2" value="1">        
<button type="button"  id="WS2inc" class="but"> + </button>
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
  $(".but").on("click",function() {
    var id=this.id;
    var fldId=id.substring(0,id.length-3);
    var inc=id.substring(id.length-3)=="inc";
    var fld = $("#"+fldId);
    var val = +fld.val();
    if (inc)val++;else val--;
    fld.val(val);
  });
});
```